# When I console.log(obj),I want to know the meaning of left string

Tags: javascript, function, object

```
var triangle = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
function ColoredTriangle() {
    this.color = 'red';
}

ColoredTriangle.prototype = triangle;
var obj = new ColoredTriangle();
console.log(obj.constructor.name, obj);
//result: Object ColoredTriangle {color: "red"}
```

I use chrome browser.

[image]

Comment: Please explain your question a little more. Is there any problem or you want explanation of the behavior of code.

Answer (score 0):

Here, `var obj = new ColoredTriangle();` using this, you are creating a new object of function `ColoredTriangle()`.

Hence, in your console result, `ColoredTriangle {color: "red"}` shows the content of the `obj` that you are printing. You can see it also shows function properties.

Answer (score 0):

`obj` is instance of the constructor `ColoredTriangle`. So the `obj.constructor` will be the function object which is  `ColoredTriangle`. `.name` will get the name of that function.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) about `Function.prototype.name`

> A Function object's read-only name property indicates the function's name as specified when it was created, or "anonymous" for functions created anonymously

See the example below.

**Note:** The `name` property is only specific for the function objects. I will not work for other datatypes.

```js
function foo(){}
let instance = new foo();
console.log(instance.constructor); //function foo(){}
console.log(foo.name) //foo
```